# How to increase values for each member of a group in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
id   group   val
a     1      10
a     2      10
a     3      10
b     1      25
b     2      25
```

I want to increase value ("val") by 1 for each group "id" "group" to make their "val" not equal. so desired result is:

```
id   group   val
a     1      10
a     2      11
a     3      12
b     1      25
b     2      26
```

How could I do that?

Comment: What have you researched and tried already?  Where specifically are you having a problem?

Comment: Do you want val to be uniques within a single group or globally unique ? Because you described the former  but the output shows the latter.

Comment: Why not just add group to val minus one? all there...

Comment: What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? Please add the tag for it.

Comment: @LukaBarisic in a single group. but each must be increased only by 1 compared to previous

Comment: @mcsoini this is example-data, there can be strings in "group" for example

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `cumcount`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'b', 4: 'b'},
                   'group': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 2},
                   'val': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 25, 4: 25}})

df["val"] += df.groupby("id").cumcount()
print(df)

  id  group  val
0  a      1   10
1  a      2   11
2  a      3   12
3  b      1   25
4  b      2   26
```

Comment: this is example-data, there can be strings in "group" for example

Comment: @lr8_mind not relevant for this answer